# Displaying different file chooser selections on different Imageviews

Tags: android, picasso

I have an activity with 5 ImageViews. I have set on click listeners for all of these views. When an image view is clicked, a file chooser is opened and once an image is picked it should be displayed in the imageview that was initially clicked. My problem is that i do not know how to identify which imageview was clicked and thus display the image on the correct view. Below is my code which, at the moment, can only display the chosen image on a 'hard-coded' view.

```
public class event_creator_view_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView display, img1,img2,img3,img4;
    private Uri imageuri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_creator_view_activity);

        display = findViewById(R.id.creator_display_image);
        img1 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img1);
        img2 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img2);
        img3 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img3);
        img4 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img4);

        display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser();
            }
        });
        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser();
            }
        });
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser();
            }
        });
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser();
            }
        });
        img4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser();
            }
        });

    }


    private void openfileChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cR = this.getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST&&resultCode==this.RESULT_OK&&data!=null&&
                data.getData()!=null){
            imageuri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageuri).into(display);
            //  uploadFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can track your clicked position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public class event_creator_view_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView display, img1,img2,img3,img4;
    private Uri imageuri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ONE = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_TWO = 2;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_THREE = 3;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FOUR = 4;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FIVE = 5;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_creator_view_activity);

        display = findViewById(R.id.creator_display_image);
        img1 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img1);
        img2 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img2);
        img3 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img3);
        img4 = findViewById(R.id.creator_img4);

        display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser(PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ONE);
            }
        });
        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser(PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_TWO);
            }
        });
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser(PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_THREE);
            }
        });
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser(PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FOUR);
            }
        });
        img4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfileChooser(PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FIVE);
            }
        });

    }


    private void openfileChooser(int requestcode){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode);
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cR = this.getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ONE&&resultCode==this.RESULT_OK&&data!=null&&
                data.getData()!=null){
            imageuri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageuri).into(display);
            //  uploadFile();
        }else if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_TWO&&resultCode==this.RESULT_OK&&data!=null&&
                data.getData()!=null){

            imageuri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageuri).into(img1);

        }else if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_THREE&&resultCode==this.RESULT_OK&&data!=null&&
                data.getData()!=null){

            imageuri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageuri).into(img2);

        }else if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FOUR&&resultCode==this.RESULT_OK&&data!=null&&
                data.getData()!=null){

            imageuri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageuri).into(img3);

        }else if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FIVE&&resultCode==this.RESULT_OK&&data!=null&&
                data.getData()!=null){

            imageuri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageuri).into(img4);
        }
    }
  }
```

I HOPE IT HELPS...

Comment: I used your logic and it worked. The only thing i did differently is pass the `PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST` variable into my `openfileChooser` method. I then retouched the if statements in the `onActivityResult` method and it worked. Thank you for opening my eyes.